# undefined result conditions forecast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I edit some code jquery weather , and when I add some Response Fields not all Fields clear result I have undefined result conditions .

Example :  Max. temp: 42C / 108F Min. temp: 27C / 80F wind :  undefined

```
$(function() { var handlers = {

simplePrint : function (location){

  var new_location_div = $('<div>');
  new_location_div.addClass('location');
  new_location_div.data('l',location.l);
  new_location_div.data('city',location.name);

  var location_p = $('<p>').text(location.name)

  new_location_div.append(location_p);

  $('#search_result').append(new_location_div);
},

displayPrint : function (location,day){

  var display = $('<div>');
  display.addClass('display_on')
  location =  $('<p>').text('Location: ' + location);
  high_temp = $('<p>').text('Max. temp: ' + day.high.celsius + 'C / ' + day.high.fahrenheit + 'F');
  min_temp = $('<p>').text('Min. temp: ' + day.low.celsius + 'C / ' + day.low.fahrenheit + 'F');
  wind_dir = $('<p>').text(' ' + day.wind_dir +' ');

  display.append(location,high_temp,min_temp,wind_dir);

  // "Thunderstorm" "Chance of Rain" "Overcast" "Partly Cloudy" "Rain" "Clear"

  $('#display_today').slideUp('slow');

  var condition = ['clear', 'sunny'].indexOf(day.conditions.toLowerCase())

  if (condition === -1 ) { 

   $('body').fadeTo('slow', 0, function()
    { 
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://harrymoroz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/1_See_It.jpg")');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
   $('h1').css({'color': 'white'});
   $('.starter-template > p').css({'color': 'white'});
  }else{

    $('body').fadeTo('slow', 0, function()
    { 
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://melodywren.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/p1040585.jpg")');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
   $('h1').css({'color': 'rgb(#333)'});
   $('p').css({'color': 'rgb(#333)'});
  };

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.display_on').remove();
    $('#display_today').append(display);
    $('#display_today').slideDown('400');
  }, '800'); } } $('#search_form_submit').on('click keypress',  function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var search_query = $('#search_field').val();
if (!search_query) {
  $('.location').remove();
  return;
};  
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=' + search_query ,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'cb', 
  })
    .done(function(search_api_answer) {
    $('.location').remove();  

  search_api_answer.RESULTS.filter(function(location){
     return location.type === 'city'
  }).forEach(handlers.simplePrint);
});

$('#search_form').trigger("reset");
    });$('#search_result').on('click', '.location', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var selected_location = $(this)

var lCode = selected_location.data('l');

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/0ce1c4a981f7dd2a/conditions/forecast/q/'+ lCode + '.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  // jsonp: 'cb',
})
.done(function(api_city_forecast,conditions) {
  todayForecast = api_city_forecast.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0];
  cityForecast = selected_location.data('city');
  conditions = conditions.current_observation;
  handlers.displayPrint(cityForecast,todayForecast,conditions);});});});
```

Comment: Change `day.wind_dir` to `day.current_observation.wind_dir`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wind_di' of undefined

Comment: `wind_dir` not `wind_di`

Comment: its same no thing change

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result of:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/0ce1c4a981f7dd2a/conditions/forecast/q/kzn.json
```

it seems that some items, like the "day" variable, may not always be filled out how like you expect. Specifically, the "day" variable in that JSON response has no "high" or "low" attribute -- it simply has a valuel.

You might want to make your app cater for this condition, ie when weatherunderground doesn't know all values for a query, but provides a base value.

Comment: in json Fields  wind_dir : NNW but in result  html i have undefined